# Can't parse integer in mysql prepared statement using util.format() in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am using util module in node.js for formatting strings. But I found a catch when I wanna run an SQL Query like -

```
select * from something LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0;
```

So what I am trying to do is, I've created a queryString then format that queryString and finally execute the query through server application. Here is the code in nodejs :

```
queryString = "select * from something LIMIT '%d' OFFSET '%d'";
query = util.format(queryString, 5, 0);
res = db.executeQuery(query);
```

I have also tried %i and %s, with quotes and without quotes but nothing worked for me.
Here is the log :

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%i OFFSET %i' at line 1
```

I am sure I am missing something here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) module

There are other ways:

```
var limit = 5;
var offset = 0;
var qs = `select * from something LIMIT ${limit} OFFSET ${offset}`;
```

or

```
connection.query('select * from something LIMIT ? OFFSET ?', [limit, offset], function (error, results, fields) {
  ...
});
```

or

```
var sql = mysql.format('select * from something LIMIT ? OFFSET ?', [limit, offset]);
```

[See docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values)

Comment: Yes I know it will work through the above ways. But want to use util module. Anyway I think util module has this catch. So I have to use other ways only.